# How to easily test my drawable, icons, splashscreens

Tags: layout, drawable

I am developing a android game with a friend of mine and I would like to ask you a question about design testing.

Currently, to test my drawable, icons ... I set them on the right size for my android phone, I save it as a PNG, transfer it on my device and only then I can test it directly on my phone ...
Also, sometimes, I set them on the right size, save the png, put it on my drawable folder and build the .apk file ...

Each of this method is a huge time cost for me ! Is there any chance a program can help not wasting my time with all this step ?
Maybe there is something allowing us to put png on a app folder and directly test it on the device ?

Thank you everobody, hope I am clear enough ^^

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/mobile/

> Until now, while remote debugging you've had to shift your eyes back
>   and forth between your device and your devtools. Now, Screencast
>   displays your devices's screen right alongside your devtools. Seeing
>   it is good, but interacting with it is even better:
>
> Clicks on the screencast are translated into taps and proper touch
>   events are fired on the device. 
>          Inspect element on your device with your desktop pointer Type on your    desktop keyboard--all keystrokes are sent to the device. A
>   huge    timesaver over typing with your thumbs.
>          Scroll the page by flinging it with your pointer or just sliding on    your laptop trackpad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have taken a look on this, seems nice ! Something else ? Someone else ?

Comment: I have just try ChromeCast. Actually, it cast my phone screen on my computer screen and I would like to do the exact opposit ^^